# Grey Prediction Model $\operatorname{GM}(1,1)$ Reference

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, time-series

I've come across several papers recently that use a prediction model called Grey Prediction $\operatorname{GM}(1,1)$, and I haven't been able to find a good (English) reference that introduces it (there are plenty of papers that use it, but that's not particularly helpful).

Can anyone point me toward a good reference?

Comment: Were you able to find anything on this? I've also been trying to read some of these papers.  I hadn't heard of it until a few days ago.